# phalcon apc cache is not working true

Tags: caching, frameworks, phalcon, apc

I am using Phalcon framework with its APC cache plugin. First I am trying

```
$this->cache->save('x', "111");
```

after i am trying

```
$this->cache->save('x', "222");
```

after when i run this:

```
 $data = $this->cache->get('x'); 
 print_r($data);
```

on browser response sometimes `111`, sometimes `222` and sometimes response `FALSE`. My APC settings below:

[image]

whats my problem. Thank you.

Comment: What is your PHP version? Post your 'cache' service definition from IoC.